# ganglia gmond sent message 'heartbeat' of length 52 with 1 errors

Tags: ganglia

I Create Ganglia Cluster, run is the gmetad service and gomnd service
see ganglia web page Find Hosts up: 0

my gomnd.conf

`globals {
         daemonize = yes
         setuid = yes
         user = xxx
         debug_level = 10
         max_udp_msg_len = 1472
         mute = no
         deaf = no
         allow_extra_data = yes
         host_dmax = 86400 
         host_tmax = 20 
         cleanup_threshold = 300 
         gexec = no
         send_metadata_interval = 0 
    }`

`cluster {
         name = "hadoop"
         owner = "xxx"
        latlong = "unspecified"
        url = "unspecified"
    }`

`host {
         location = "vmlin0427"
    }`

`udp_send_channel {
         host = xx.xx.xx.xxx #My hadoop NameNode
         port = 8653
         ttl = 1
    }`

`udp_recv_channel {
         port = 8653
    }`

`tcp_accept_channel {
         port = 8653
         gzip_output = no
    }`

my gmetad.conf

`data_source "hadoop" xx.xx.xx.xx:8653`

See configuration does not seem to be a problem

gomnd debug=10 log message

`Mar 28 15:19:22 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12637]:   [PYTHON]`
 `Can't open the python module path    /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012`
`Mar 28 15:19:22 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12637]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012
Mar 28 15:26:05 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12686]: [PYTHON] Can't open the python module path /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012
Mar 28 15:26:05 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12686]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012
Mar 28 15:26:05 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12686]: Error 1 sending the modular data for gexec#012
Mar 28 15:44:39 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12812]: [PYTHON] Can't open the python module path /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012
Mar 28 15:44:39 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12812]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012
Mar 28 15:56:23 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12879]: [PYTHON] Can't open the python module path /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012
Mar 28 15:56:23 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12879]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012
Mar 28 15:58:32 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12922]: [PYTHON] Can't open the python module path /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012
Mar 28 15:58:32 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12922]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012
Mar 28 15:58:32 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12922]: Error creating UDP server on port 8653 bind=10.96.140.112.  Will try again...#012
Mar 28 15:59:01 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12935]: [PYTHON] Can't open the python module path /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012
Mar 28 15:59:01 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12935]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012
Mar 28 15:59:01 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[12935]: Error creating UDP server on port 8653 bind=10.96.140.112.  Will try again...#012
Mar 28 16:30:40 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13110]: [PYTHON] Can't open the python module path /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012
Mar 28 16:30:40 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13110]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012
Mar 28 16:44:38 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13227]: [PYTHON] Can't open the python module path /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012
Mar 28 16:44:38 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13227]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012
Mar 28 16:51:59 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13265]: [PYTHON] Can't open the python module path /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012
Mar 28 16:51:59 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13265]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012
Mar 28 17:12:23 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13401]: [PYTHON] Can't open the python module path /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012
Mar 28 17:12:23 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13401]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012
Mar 28 17:12:23 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13401]: Error 1 sending the modular data for proc_total#012
Mar 28 17:12:23 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13401]: Error 1 sending the modular data for mem_free#012
Mar 28 17:13:03 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13401]: Error 1 sending the modular data for mem_free#012
Mar 28 17:13:43 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13401]: Error 1 sending the modular data for mem_free#012
Mar 28 17:14:23 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13401]: Error 1 sending the modular data for mem_free#012
Mar 28 17:15:03 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13401]: Error 1 sending the modular data for mem_free#012
Mar 28 17:15:43 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13401]: Error 1 sending the modular data for mem_free#012
Mar 28 17:26:31 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13462]: [PYTHON] Can't open the python module path /usr/local/ganglia/lib64/ganglia/python_modules.#012
Mar 28 17:26:31 vmlin0427 /usr/local/ganglia/sbin/gmond[13462]: Module python_module failed to initialize.#012`

I have been debugging for many days, but it has not been solved.
Also encountered the same problem to provide some of the ideas of a friend

Thanks!